# What does "bounded above" mean in Family of Bachmann–Landau notations?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, asymptotics, big-o-notation

Per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)

> |f| is bounded above by g (up to constant factor) asymptotically

with this concrete example,

$$f(n) = \log n$$

$$g(n) = n^c = n^{0.000001}$$

Does "bounded above (up to constant factor)" means $f(n)$ is above $g(n)$

Comment: Yes, isn't that exactly what Wikipedia says? It's in the description cell for that row.

Comment: @Juho thank you, just to confirm my understanding is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantity $a$ is *bounded above* by a quantity $b$ if $a \leq b$.

A quantity $a$ is *bounded above (up to constant factor)* by a quantity $b$ if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $a \leq Cb$. (This makes sense when $a,b$ depend on some other variable).

A quantity $a(n)$ is *bounded above (up to constant factor) asymptotically* by a quantity $b(n)$ if there exist constants $N,C>0$ such that $a(n) \leq Cb(n)$ for all $n \geq N$. This is usually expressed as $a(n) = O(b(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

"$x$ is bounded above by $y$" just means that $x\leq y$.

Comment: It says “up to constant factor”.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The question asks what "bounded above" means. The example sentence also includes other words but the question doesn't ask about those.